# ORACLE accessing PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I don't have PUPBLD.SQL to run. I find and download it but after running I still have this problem.

Comment: What does `SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'audit_trail';` say, and  `SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs;`, and finally `SELECT tablespace_name, bytes, maxbytes FROM dba_data_files WHERE tablespace_name LIKE 'SYS%';`

Comment: There are two separate, unrelated errors here: the PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE issue, and the ORA-65096 invalid common user or role name error. Are you looking for help with both, or just the missing table error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood what you meant by saying that you "don't have it". It is part of Oracle installation and can be found in your `\server` directory (for example, on my 11gXE it is in `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\`).

I don't know whether that file's contents changes with Oracle database versions, but - you should run the one that comes with your database, not just any you manage to download from some (unknown?) source on the Internet.

Furthermore, you should have run it while connected as `SYSTEM`. Reading your post, it is unclear whether you did it or not.  If not, you should have. But, `SYSTEM` (as well as `SYS`) are *administrative* users and not everyone can use them; DBA can. Are you a DBA on your database? If not, I believe you should contact them and see whether they can help.

Finally, [PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE Table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_nine.htm#SQPUG568) documentation (related to 12c; see the same document for your database version).

Comment: OK, first I can't find PUPBLD.SQL but now I find its location and run as sys. I still have the same errors

Comment: You should run the script as SYSTEM, not SYS. Also, the invalid common user name error is a separate issue.